# Construction of a "density" or a Radon-Nikodym for a Semicontinuous Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I just started self-studying measure theory and had a question about the "generalised density" ([as it appears on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition)):

> A random variable X with values in a measurable space $({\mathcal{X}},{\mathcal {A}})$ (usually $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$ with the Borel sets
>   as measurable subsets) has as probability distribution the measure $X_*P$ on $({\mathcal {X}},{\mathcal {A}})$: the density of $X$ with
>   respect to a reference measure $\mu$ on $({\mathcal {X}},{\mathcal{A}})$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative:
>
> $$f={\frac {dX_{*}P}{d\mu }}.$$

For a random variable $X$, if we had a cumulative distribution function:

$$F(X) = \begin{cases} 0 & if \; X < 0 \\ X^2 & if \; 0 \leq X < 0.8 \\ 1 & if \; X \geq 0.8 \end{cases}$$

... that looks like:

[image: CDF]

Then, does a "generalised density" or a Radon-Nikodym derivative as defined above exist?

---

I think that it does... If $\mathcal X = [0, 0.8) \cup \{0.8\}$, for an appropriate $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$, could one use the "reference measure":

$$\mu = l + \delta_{0.8}$$

... where $l$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\delta_{0.8}$ is the Dirac measure on $\{0.8\}$? I'd also love some help clarifying what $X_*P$ is (is this a "pushforward measure", and if so, is this the same as the "measure induced by the CDF"?)

If one *can* use the reference measure above, why can we use it? And would the Radon-Nikodym derivative be:

$$f = \frac{dX_*P}{d\mu} = 2X * \mathcal I(X \in [0, 0.8)) + 0.2 * \mathcal I(X = 0.8)$$

where $\mathcal I$ is the indicator function?

Comment: You can only ask about existence of RND w.r.t. a given reference measure. Every measure is absolutely continuous w.r.t. itself  with density $1$ so your question does not make sense.Also do not use the same symbols $X$ for a random variable and  a real variable used to define its distribution function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what if the reference measure was the sum of lebesgue measure and a dirac measure on the set $\{0.8\}$?

Comment: If that is the reference measure then we do have  absolute continuity and hence  RND exists.

Comment: Could you please post a proof or a very rough sketch and what the RND looks like? I'd be really grateful!!

Comment: The RND is $0$ for $x<0$ as well as $x>0.8$, $2x$ for $0\leq x <0.8$ and $[1-(0,8)^{2}]$ for $x=0.8$